# linked style background-image not applying to html hrefs

Tags: hyperlink, css-selectors, background-image, pseudo-element

i have a link css file but the background image in my html is not applying to the hyperlinks in the html code

i created a style.css file and in that script, there is a background-image which also contains a ::before pseudo element. The pseudo element is applying in the hrefs of the main html but the background-image is not applying

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.